# Loop cut and slide modifying UVs in unexpected way

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv

I'm bridging two edge loops as shown in the following image:[image]
The upper portion is the UV map and the below portion is the mesh in edit mode. Once after bridging the edge loops, when I'm trying to divide the bridged edge loops using loop cut and slide, the loops are being added perfectly well in the mesh,but in the UVs, they are coming parallel to the bridged edges and not perpendicular as shown in the following two images.

After bridging the loops
[image]

After loop cut and slide
[image]

How should I correct the UV after loop cut and slide action?

Comment: This seems to be a bug of Bridge. If you fill those faces manually with F or with F2 addon then there won't be any problem while loop cutting. Or if you reunwrap again. But if using Bridge what is shown on the screenshot will be present regardless of what way to use for loop cut - Ctrl+R or Bridge options.

Comment: This is what is happening (the link has the image) when I manually put a face in the bottom most 4 points to use f2 add-on. https://goo.gl/RMbHzb . The face doesn't form properly in the UV map. One point is at the bottom left corner of the UV map.

Comment: @Sum-Al - I can confirm that manual face creation and F2 *are working* as expected with the UV.  I'm not sure what's going on with your setup.  How did you do your unwrap?

Comment: unwrapped by 'project from view' (top view)

Comment: @Sum-Al - that's exactly what I used and I had no issue... strange.  The edge loop bridge did exactly as you described though.